# Save UIImage into a specific PhotoAlbum

Tags: iphone, uiimage

Is it possible to create a folder into a photo album where i can save my UIImage?
I use - UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum but i can't chose the specific Photo Album

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the current SDK (4.1 and lower).